# I cant get my dialog check box to work in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Im trying to have a button that says "choose drink" when the user clicks the button a dialog appears with a list of drinks that i have stored in an array.

I know the problem is where ive said "boolean is checked" but I need that because my items are stored in an array. someone help please!
if i remove boolean is checked then i obviously get an error on the if statement where it says "isChecked"

```
package com.example.liamchowney.myappoctober;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;




public class Multiselection extends DialogFragment {

private static TextView text_view;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //to store selection

@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final String [] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_drinks_selection); //gets array items to screen
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose drink").setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.my_drinks_selection, null, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {
                list.add(items[which]); //adds selected item
            }
            else if(list.contains(items[which]))
            {
                list.remove(items[which]); //removes selected item if they uncheck
            }

        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //to display the selected item done by user

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String selections = ""; //default value
            for(String ms : list)
            {
                selections = selections + "\n" +ms;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Drink Selection :" +selections, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    return builder.create();
   }
}
```

Comment: When does the error happens and how?

Comment: currently i get an error (red underline) on dialogInterface.OnclickListener saying class anonymous 'class derived from onclicklistener' then i also have a red underline on the override thats underneath it. when i remove "boolean is checked" these errors go but then the if statement doesnt work

Comment: That's because you added an extra parameter to the `onClick`, when that method does not exist for `DialogInterface.OnClick`.

Comment: yes i know that but i need that parameter what else can i use instead?

Comment: You say checkbox in your title, but in your code you're using `setSingleChoiceItems` which results in a radio button list. Which one do you want? Checkboxes(multiple choices), or radio buttons(single choice)?

Comment: radiobuttons single choice, sorry i havent viewed this too see what it looks like yet cause obviously it wont load

Comment: I just want a user to be able to select an item from a list thats stored in my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    list.add(items[which]);
}
```

if you're working with a single choice radio button. This well select the item at the specified index. That's all you need to add your item.

I wouldn't suggest a list to add items for a single choice option. Instead assign the index to a variable and then add that variable to your list when you hit `OK` otherwise you have unnecessary remove logic for a single choice option.

For your items:

```
onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    mySelectedChoice = which;
}
```

For your button:

```
onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    list.add(items[mySelectedChoice]);
    //rest of your logic
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply. So your saying dont use an array list?

Comment: The only error im getting now is a cannot resolve method "mySelectedChoice"

Comment: Either set `mySelectedChoice` as a global variable or use a setter method for it. Then retrieve it after. You should use an `ArrayList` for multi-choice options, it's redundant for single-choice, unless you're adding all those single choice options to one final list.